# Query with Linq and count matches in the Where clause and project it

Tags: c#, linq

Need to query many columns for possible matches and then see how many did match and add that to a column in the Select projection. I could have two column of the four match but how many did? Then want to sort the result by how many matches. Do I need to group them first? Do a separate aggregation? Kind of stumped as which way to go because the real one would have a lot more tests of fields in production. Could possibly match as many as 8 tests in the where clause.

```
    var results = _RList
       .Where(d => d.RMI15Min == RMI.ConfirmedBottom || d.RMI15Min == RMI.InPlaceBottomConfirmed
        || d.RMI30Min == RMI.ConfirmedBottom || d.RMI30Min == RMI.InPlaceBottomConfirmed)
       .OrderBy(d => d.Instrument)
       .Select(d => new
       {
           d.Instrument,
           d.Description,
           d.RMI15Min,
           d.RMI30Min,
           NewColumn with the total of the matches in the .Where clause above. 
       }).ToList();
```

Comment: Only works for the first test and returns a bool, not a int of how many.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `_RList` does not tie back to a database table

```cs
var confirmedList = new List<int> { RMI.ConfirmedBottom, RMI.InPlaceBottomConfirmed };
var results = _RList
       .OrderBy(d => d.Instrument)
       .Select(d => new
       {
           d.Instrument,
           d.Description,
           d.RMI15Min,
           d.RMI30Min,
           Count = (new List<int> { d.RMI15Min, d.RMI30Min }).Count(c => confirmedList.Contains(c))
       })
       .Where(d => d.Count > 0)
       .ToList();
```

If it ties back to a database table, it depends on whether your library can convert the above LINQ statement.

Comment: Wow I think you fixed about four things in my example. This is a beautiful example of how to clean up  a linq query. Tip of the hat, nod of the head.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider using ternary operators to add 1/0 to the total;

```cs
Count = (d.RMI15Min == RMI.ConfirmedBottom ? 1 : 0)
    + (d.RMI15Min == RMI.InPlaceBottomConfirmed ? 1 : 0)
    + (d.RMI30Min == RMI.ConfirmedBottom ? 1 : 0)
    + (d.RMI30Min == RMI.InPlaceBottomConfirmed ? 1 : 0)
```

Then filter the list after calculating the count.